# How to add data from a Range to an ActiveX ListBox?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox

Below I have a macro that forms an array from a range, and posts it into an `ActiveX ListBox`.

The code works, but the constant posting to the spreadsheet is slow. Is there a way to post the entire array to the `ListBox` more efficiently?

See code below:

```vb
Sub Test()
    'Lets format and populate the Listbox102
    Dim p as integer, i as integer, j as integer, FinalCombinedArray as variant
    FinalCombinedArray=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A1:D300")
    'Keep track of where the scrollbar is currently
    p = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.TopIndex
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.Clear
    'Inset array element by element
    For i = 1 To UBound(FinalCombinedArray, 2)
        For j = 1 To UBound(FinalCombinedArray, 1)
            If i = 1 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.AddItem
            End If
            'Format array numbers
            If ((j + 1) Mod 14) = 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.List(j - 1, i - 1) = Format(FinalCombinedArray(j, i), "#,##0.0000")
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.List(j - 1, i - 1) = Format(FinalCombinedArray(j, i), "#,##0.00")
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.AddItem
    'If possible, bring scrollbar back to where it was
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.ListCount - 1 > p Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102.TopIndex = p
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using the Range Reference

If you are already using an `ActiveX ListBox` and your data is in a Range, why not just use the [ListFillRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.controlformat.listfillrange) property?

Using this method will fill your `ListBox` with all the values and retain the general formatting as well.

[image: Properties example]

---

### Using the List Property

On my second glance I see your example is using data from multiple columns. In that case, if you desire a single column `ListBox`, then you could use the [ListBox.List Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/listbox-control-list-property-example) and load your values from a single dimension array.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A1:D300").value` returns a two dimension array, so it would need to be converted to a single dimension array. Below are two helper functions that do just that.

```vb
' Helper function to get the number
' of elements from an array from a specific dimension
Public Function ArrayLength(source As Variant, Optional dimension As Long = 1) As Long
    ArrayLength = UBound(source, dimension) - LBound(source, dimension) + 1
End Function

' Convert two dim array to a single dim array
Public Function ToSingleArray(twoDimArray As Variant) As Variant
    ' Get an empty array with needed number of elements
    ' (row * column)
    Dim temp As Variant
    ReDim temp(0 To (ArrayLength(twoDimArray, 1) * ArrayLength(twoDimArray, 2)))
    
    ' Loop first columns then rows.
    Dim column As Long
    For column = LBound(twoDimArray, 2) To UBound(twoDimArray, 2)
        Dim row As Long
        For row = LBound(twoDimArray, 1) To UBound(twoDimArray, 1)
            Dim current As Long
            
            ' Add item to the single dim array.
            temp(current) = twoDimArray(row, column)
            current = current + 1
        Next row
    Next column
    
    ' Return the new single dim array.
    ToSingleArray = temp
End Function
```

Formatting won't be preserved in these, so if that's desired a modified version of the function can be created, or the array can be mapped over and formatted.

Once you have your list of items, it's as simple as `.List = yourArray`. Below is a simplified version of your example

```vb
Public Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").ListBox102
        .Clear
        .List = ToSingleArray(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A1:D300").Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `List` accepts a 2D array (but you need to set the `ColumnCount` property accordingly)

Comment: You are correct, Thanks for adding that tidbit! That would be the way to go if multiple columns are desired for the `ListBox`. If a single column is the desire, then use the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the listbox in one shot by assigning the full array, instead of item-by-item

Very basic example: fill a listbox using the selected range

```vb
Dim rng As Range, arr
    
Set rng = Selection
arr = rng.Value
    
'optionally run over arr and format values if required

Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count
Me.ListBox1.List = arr
```